# appending value in python and writing to a file

Tags: python, list, file-io, append, classification

I have made a classifier in Python and it works fine. Now I need to output the results into a text file, which I can also do without a problem. The problem is, I need to include the id of the result as well as the result itself. I am new to python and still getting used to the syntax so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    printedRow = '{id1},{result1}'.format(id1=id , result1 = result)
    print("~~~~~RESULT~~~~~")

    for k in range(0,len(pans)):
         pans.append(row[0] + ','+ p.classify(row))

    print (pans)
    print(pans, file=outfile)
```

The id that I need to include with the results of the classifier is being held in the index row[0]. When I run this code, the same id is printed with every result. The results are printing out fine, I just need to be able to match the id with the result.

They are both held in lists and there are about 2000 values in each list.

Comment: Can you give us the values of pans and row so we can see what we are working with?

Comment: pans contains the results for the classifier such result can be either '<=50k','>50k' or 'unknown'. the values for the row are as follows 'id1', 'id453'.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - the actual values don't matter much, what matters is the data structures, are they lists? How many values will they contain at the start of execution of this bit of code? Also, it's easiest to give the information by editing your answer.

Comment: OK, so what exactly are you trying to do here? You are looping over the length of pans,then adding the id and the output of `classify()` of the entire row to pans. This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i am trying to loop through 'row[0]' taking each value and printing it to the file beside the output of 'classify()' that it is associated to. so that the output would read.

        'id1, <50k' , 'id2, >50k', etc

Comment: You say you want to loop through `row[0]`, so `row` is a list of lists? This would be a lot easier if you could show us example input (only 5 values, say, not 2000), and example output, so we know what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do because you don't define what `row` or `pans` are. Consider using more Pythonic source code.  If an object is a collection of any type, then use some sort of iterator. Enumerate is useful to give each loop an index number.

```
for n, p in enumerate(pans):
    print "pan %d is %s" % (n, p)
```

You also appear to be appending to `pans` within a loop whose size depends on `pans`. That could go on forever!

If you want to add to a list, just add it, e.g.:

```
newpans = pans + [x.classify(row) for x in oldpans]
```

Rather than building up a structure in memory, then printing it to a file, write directly to a file. This will use up far less memory. If you want speed, let the computer buffer the file for you, e.g.

```
f = open("output.txt", "w")
for n, p in enumerate(pans):
    f.write("%s,%s\n" % (n, classify(p)))
f.close()
```